# Randomly distribute people into groups based on condition

Tags: python, vba, grouping

I have a list of people with their departments. I'm trying to distribute them into groups of equal size with the condition that they are not with people from their own departments where possible. I've got a list of 417 people with 19 departments and trying to put them in groups of 10.

Here is an example to illustrate what I mean:

```
Name   Department
 1   |     A 
 2   |     B
 3   |     B 
 4   |     C
 5   |     C
 6   |     C
 7   |     D
 8   |     D
 9   |     D
10   |     E
```

So here for example, if grouping in 3s I'd get something like
[1, 4, 7], [3, 6, 9], [2, 10], [5, 8]

Is there any known algorithm that fixes this problem. I currently have a dataframe that has a similar list to the one illustrated above but unsure on how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have them sorted by department, with numeric "names", the solution is short.

```
df.groupby(int("Name")%10)
```

If my pre-conditions are wrong, then sort your DF by department, and then distribute by `row` instead of the numeric name.

Comment: I haven't got them with numeric ''names", just put it in that format so my example would be clear. What do you mean by distribute by row? Would that make it so that in each group of 10 there aren't members of the same department?

Comment: Provided that there are no more than 10 members in any department, then this does guarantee no overlap; if there are more, then the pigeonhole principle says there's no solution.

Comment: The distribution means that you use the row number instead of the name to determine that person's group.

Comment: Ah thanks but there is more than 10 members in any department, some have 50 others 30 some 5.

Comment: As I already said: if you have more members in a department than you have groups, then it is impossible to avoid having multiple department members in one group.